# Is it possible to create Excel VBA Code Library that several workbooks share?

Tags: vba, excel

I have several workbooks that have similar and reused VBA code sometimes I need to update the code and I would like to do this in one place instead of in 20 different workbooks is this possible?

If not is there a way to copy all the macros from one workbook to all the others after a change has been made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, yes.

[This answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/854232/277757) mentions one possibility that is explored more in-depth [in this support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566).

> If you find yourself recreating the same macros, you can copy those
>   macros to a special workbook called Personal.xlsb that is saved on
>   your computer.
>
> By default, when you create a macro in Excel, the macro works only in
>   the workbook that contains it. This behavior is okay as long as you
>   don’t need to use that macro in other workbooks. Any macros that you
>   store in your personal workbook on a computer become available to you
>   in any workbook whenever you start Excel on that same computer.

In short: record a macro and choose to save it in `Personal Macro Workbook`. Save and exit, then re-open Excel. Go to the View-tab and click unhide.

The support article gives a more detailed step-by-step.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can reference other workbooks from VBA. Might be easiest to put it in an addin though.

If you are using class modules, then you can only set them as either private or public not createable (something like that).  Obviously they'll need to be public, but you can get around the inability to create them by building simple helper functions in a normal module that do nothing other than create a new instance of the class and return it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure is possible, 
the two ways that I know are:
copy your macros on Personal.xlsb (like Vegard wrote) or (it's my usually case because I've also my custom Ribbon to play all my custom cmd) you can open a new excel file, write in this file all your macro/function/class.... and then save it as xlam file.
After you need to go on excel option, add components and choice the xlam file before created.
Tips, in the xlam file use a specific macro names and not macro1, macro2,.... because into your next files will be easy to create more macro and use the same name is usually..

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my answer based on experience as it seems the ones given are all (unspoken) focused on being "free".

I started out using a workbook as my code library (as suggested above), but every time I made an adjustement or improvement to those code snippets, I had to go back to the other workbook and update it etc. This got old fast.

Once I started developing a bit more professionally, it made sense to **invest in a tool to manage my code**.

I use [MZTools](https://www.mztools.com/) which also comes highly recommended by various Excel MVPs such as Ken Puls, Ro Bovey, etc. but there are other ones out there. Usually these tools also provide addtional functionalities that are useful to a developer. Invest a few bucks if you want to save your self from a headache.

Comment: PS: I'm not affiliated with MZ Tools or anything, I just like the product.

Comment: MZTools is great! Also RubberDuck

Comment: I use RubberDuck as well : )  ...testing routines are a great thing to have in larger applications